# DevExtreme dxTreeList height dilemma

Tags: devextreme-angular

I've looked at the documentation for dxTreeList, and it says that if I specify the height of the control (e.g. `100%`), the treelist control will constrain itself within the parent container and display the appropriate scrollbars. I've tried setting scrolling to both virtual and standard, by the way.

What I'm observing is that the control ignores the height specified altogether. For instance:

```
    <dx-tree-list
        height="40vh"
        ....>
```

Results in a treelist control that will ignore the setting, and grow in size as I expand out the nodes.  This is problematic as the expanded control now scrolls well past the parent container, and when I scroll down, the field heading scroll out of view.

I'm wondering if setting the height on the control itself is not enough. Naturally, I've set the parent div for the treelist to a specific height as well (I've tried all kinds of height measures, vh, px, %, etc etc).

Would really appreciate it if anyone has any ideas or suggestions for where else I can look.

Answer (score 0):

In my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ovw942pp0z), everything works fine. Can you provide your example or edit it?

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please post your code here. Alternatively if you just require more info from the Original Poster, you can do so as a comment once you have enough reputation.

Comment: I can't post my code because of IP restrictions, but I believe this is related to embedding a deeply nested set of `<router-outlet>` tags, with the tree list as the most deeply nested element. On top of that, there are several `<div>` elements in this hierarchy and I have the most immediate div container over the treelist router outlet imposing the height/width. I've tried both percentages, vh, and px, but no avail so far.

Comment: @teabagp, I took your sample and added it to my project, as a router outlet, and got the same problem. It's clearly related to router-outleting.